# elisp widgets: Modifying an editable-field's value real time when changing another one

Tags: elisp, widget

<sup>This is  cross-post from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188421/elisp-widgets-modifying-an-editable-fields-value-real-time-when-changing-anoth)</sup>

I have a simple widget setup:

```
(setq gobgen-widget-name
      (widget-create 'editable-field
                     :size 25
                     :format "Name:   %v"
                     :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
                               (widget-value-set gobgen-widget-prefix (get-gobject-prefix (widget-value widget))))
                     "g_example_object"))

(widget-insert " ")

(setq gobgen-widget-prefix
      (widget-create 'editable-field
                     :size 10
                     :format "Prefix: %v\n"
                     "g"))
```

I’d like to update the second widget real time with the return value of `get-gobject-prefix`.

However, whenever I enter a character in the `Name` widget, point automatically jumps to the last character of the `Prefix` field, and inserts my character there.

Is there a way to do what I’m trying to achieve?

(I’m using Emacs 24.3.1)

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged . see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068

Comment: Sorry, I discovered the Emacs site after posting to SO and thought it might better fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was easier than I expected: using `save-excursion` saved the day (and my point position).

```
(lambda (widget &rest ignore)
  (save-excursion
    (widget-value-set gobgen-widget-prefix (get-gobject-prefix (widget-value widget)))))
```

Not totally perfect, though, as it changes the width of the `Prefix` widget.